# Android Oreo JobIntentServices closes always

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler, android-8.1-oreo

I already tried a JobService as well, but I get the same result, as with the JobIntentService, namely my Notification gets called after x seconds when the app is running in the foreground, but not after swiping the app in the recent task area.

Here is how I start the JobIntentService from my Fragment:

```html
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlertJob.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", timeForAlarm);

        AlertJob.enqueueWork(getContext(), serviceIntent);
```

And this is my JobIntentService Class:

```html
public class AlertJob extends JobIntentService {

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, AlertJob.class, 123, work);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent)
    {

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service_Notification.class));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopCurrentWork() {
        return super.onStopCurrentWork();
    }
}
```

I have already tried the AlarmManager and so on as well, but the problem remains the same. The JobIntentService gets destroyed when the app is only running in the background.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Assuming you get as far as the `startService` line .. you can't call `startService()` from the background - it will throw an `IllegalStateException`, use `startForegroundService()` - on the proviso that the launched service will promote itself to foreground service within a few seconds otherwise it will close with `IllegalStateException` - docs : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService & article : https://medium.com/til-kotlin/jobintentservice-for-background-processing-on-android-o-39535460e060

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your fast answer, but somehow the Notification and startActivity() don't work after I swiped the app. :/

Comment: Maybe you could also check my other Thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510275/android-oreo-jobintentservices-closes-always